# Creating a second option window in Swing programming

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am doing a homework assignment, which pretty much asks the user to choose between two rooms and calculates how much it would cost to stay in that room for a certain number of weeks.

So I'm trying to have my program start out by asking to choose between the rooms, and then, after that choice is made, to have the user input a certain number of weeks, and multiply the cost of the room by number of weeks.

I think I have the first part of my code done, but I am totally lost on how to create the second part.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class hotel extends JFrame {
JCheckBox b1, b2, b3;
JPanel p1;
JLabel l;
JTextField t;

hotel() {
    setTitle("Hotel Room Selection");
    setSize(300,400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    l = new JLabel("Hotel.");
    t = new JTextField("Select a room type");

    b1 = new JCheckBox("b1");
    b2 = new JCheckBox("b2");
    b3 = new JCheckBox("b3");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    p1.add(b1);
    p1.add(b2);
    p1.add(b3);
    p1.add(l);
    p1.add(t);

    b1.addItemListener(new cbListener());
    b2.addItemListener(new cbListener());
    b3.addItemListener(new cbListener());   

    setVisible(true);
}

class cbListener implements ItemListener{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent b)   
    {
        if(b.getSource() == b1)
        {
            if (b1.isSelected())
            {   
                int room1 = 600;
            }

        }
        else if (b.getSource() == b2)
        {
            if (b2.isSelected())
            {   
                int room2=850;
            }

        }
         if (b.getSource() == b3)
        {
            if (b3.isSelected())
            {   
                int boat=60;
            }

            }   
        }

    }

public static void main(String [] args)
{
        Hotel a1 = new Hotel();
}}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to use the GUI? It would be much easier without it.

Comment: First you need to add the panel into the frame. Then you need to set some instance variable to the dollar amount per day. Then you need to have a whole 'nother panel beside the one you have to collect number of days and such. (You could just use fields or a spinner in the same panel.) Are you allowed to use a "calculate" button so you don't have to detect when the user changes the number of days?

Comment: @LeeMeador I think so, like say for example i chose room 1, and i wanted it for a week, i would hit the calculate button and have my final value

Comment: That means you need a text field they can type in the number of days (or some other gui component that allows entering numbers) and a button. Put a listener on the button that recalculates if any of the checkboxes are checked. No need for listeners on the check boxes. The listener on the calculate button would know how much each of the three checkboxes have for a daily cost.

Comment: @LeeMeador If you know the answer, then why don't you post it as an answer? I'll upvote it if you do.

Comment: @LeeMeador am i using the listeners correctly right now?  i feel like im not.

Comment: @AbdullahTamimi You should probably use an `ActionListener` instead of an `ItemListener`.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your issues, this is what I came up with. I kept it as simple as I could to meet your needs. There is a comment on most lines.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;

public class HotelFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel lblTotalCost;
    private JRadioButton rdbtnRoomSuite;
    private JRadioButton rdbtnRoomStandard;

    private double totalCost = 0;
    private double cost = 0;
    private JSpinner spinner;

    // Room Costs
    private final double SUITE_COST = 300.00;
    private final double STANDARD_COST = 100.00;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public HotelFrame()
    {
        // Frame Values
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 263, 147);

        // Primary Panel
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        // Panel for room type and a border
        JPanel panelRoomType = new JPanel();
        panelRoomType.setBorder(new TitledBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TitledBorder.border"), "Room Type", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
        contentPane.add(panelRoomType);
        panelRoomType.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        // Standard room radio button
        rdbtnRoomStandard = new JRadioButton("Standard");
        panelRoomType.add(rdbtnRoomStandard);

        // Add Action Listener to standard radio button
        rdbtnRoomStandard.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

        // Suite room radio button
        rdbtnRoomSuite = new JRadioButton("Suite");
        panelRoomType.add(rdbtnRoomSuite);

        // Add Action Listener to Suite radio button
        rdbtnRoomSuite.addActionListener(new RadioButtonListener());

        // Button group to link standard/suite radio buttons
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(rdbtnRoomStandard);
        group.add(rdbtnRoomSuite);

        // Panel for calculating cost
        JPanel panelCostCalc = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panelCostCalc);
        panelCostCalc.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));

        // Label for weeks
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Weeks");
        panelCostCalc.add(lblNewLabel);

        // Spinner to select week
        spinner = new JSpinner();
        panelCostCalc.add(spinner);

        // Change Listener for updating the week
        spinner.addChangeListener(new SpinnerListener());

        // Label displaying total costs - Field Variable
        lblTotalCost = new JLabel("Total Cost = $0.00");
        panelCostCalc.add(lblTotalCost);
    }

    /**
     * Update Total Cost and Label
     */
    private void updateTotalCost()
    {
        // Week value was changed. Recalculate total
        totalCost = cost * (Integer) spinner.getValue();

        // Formatter for currency
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        // Update Total Cost label
        lblTotalCost.setText("Total Cost = " + fmt.format(totalCost));
    }

    /**
     * Action Listener class for radio buttons
     */
    class RadioButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
        {
            // Room was selected
            if(a.getSource().equals(rdbtnRoomStandard))
            {
                // Standard room selected
                cost = STANDARD_COST;

            }
            else  if(a.getSource().equals(rdbtnRoomSuite))
            {
                // Suite room selected
                cost = SUITE_COST;
            }

            // Ensure total cost is updated
            updateTotalCost();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Change Listener class for week spinner
     */
    class SpinnerListener implements ChangeListener
    {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
        {
            updateTotalCost();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HotelFrame frame = new HotelFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should limit the number of frames/windows you dump onto the user.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames: Good or Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) for some more details.

Instead, I would create each "screen" in a separate `JPanel` and the use something like a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch between these views as required.